# Validating if Jtextfield matches MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, database, new-project

I'm new to java and I'm making a ATM/bank app as small project to enhance my skills. I'm trying to see if it is possible to validate the Jtextfield to MySQL database. I have learnt how to validate inputted text in the console i.e.

Enter name : BOB ,
Sorry this doesn't match the database.

However, when trying to do similar for Jtextfield it won't work. I'm also trying to do OOP so I have a class for MySQL userDatabase and a separate class for Controller/Main page.

I have uploaded the scanner method I mentioned before as my textfield code is shambles
MySQL class (p.s sorry for messy code)
`public class UsersDatabase {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/atm";
    String uname = "root";
    String password = "root";
    //scans input
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    //captures string
    String name = sc.next();
    //String communicates with db
    String query = "SELECT * FROM AtmUsers WHERE First_Name = '" + name + "'" ;

    //check if it works
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //test
    try {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, uname, password);
        //communicate with db
        Statement statement = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);

        //check whether we received anything
        if (rs.next())
            System.out.println("Success");
        else
            System.out.println("Failure!");

    }catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}`

Main class

```
 public String userInput;
Users users = new Users();
UsersDatabase usersDatabase = new UsersDatabase();


public void check(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    userInput = number.getText();
    String userPinCheck = pin.getText();
    // check account number
    if (usersDatabase.equals()) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setTitle("Error Dialog");
        alert.setHeaderText(null);
        alert.setContentText("Please make sure that your account exists");
        alert.showAndWait();
    }
```

so i tried multiple stuff in the userDatabase.equals() but as I said I cant figure it out so any help/advice would be great.
Thank You!!

Comment: You need to break out functionality of the `UserDatabase` class into separate methods, currently everything is in the `main` method which won't help you very much. You can then call the appropriate methods in the `UserDatabase` class from the `Main` class, for example: to check if an account exists.

Comment: Also, please try use `PreparedStatement`s, otherwise your code will be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-preparedstatement-in-java/